# Trying to use System.out as a task in an RDD

Tags: java, apache-spark, serialization, task

I am currently just starting out to learn Apache Spark, and had code that I can't quite figure out why is not compiling. It says the task that I am sending into the myRDD forEach is not serializable however a tutorial I am watching did a similar thing as well. Any Ideas or clues would be greatly appreciated.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Logger.getLogger("org.apache").setLevel(Level.WARN);
        List<Integer> inputData = new ArrayList<>();

        inputData.add(25);


        SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("startingSpark").setMaster("local[*]");
        JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);

        JavaRDD<Integer> myRDD = sc.parallelize(inputData);
        Integer result = myRDD.reduce((x, y) -> x + y);

        myRDD.foreach( System.out::println );
        System.out.println(result);

        sc.close();

    }
}
```

Stack Trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable...
    at com.virtualpairprogrammers.Main.main(Main.java:26)
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: java.io.PrintStream
Serialization stack:
    - object not serializable (class: java.io.PrintStream, value: java.io.PrintStream@11a82d0f)
    - element of array (index: 0)
    - array (class [Ljava.lang.Object;, size 1)...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use Lambda reference. It will try to pass the function `println(..)` of `PrintStream` to executors. Remember all the methods that you pass or put in spark closure (inside map/filter/reduce etc) must be serialised. Since `println(..)` is part of `PrintStream`, the class `PrintStream` must be serialized.

Pass an anonymous function as below-

```java
myRDD.foreach(integer -> System.out.println(integer));
```

**`Full Example`**

```java
import org.apache.log4j.Level;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Test63321956 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Logger.getLogger("org.apache").setLevel(Level.WARN);
        List<Integer> inputData = new ArrayList<>();

        inputData.add(25);


        SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("startingSpark").setMaster("local[*]");
        JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);

        JavaRDD<Integer> myRDD = sc.parallelize(inputData);
        Integer result = myRDD.reduce(Integer::sum);

        myRDD.collect().forEach( System.out::println );
        myRDD.foreach(integer -> System.out.println(integer));
        System.out.println(result);
        /**
         * 25
         * 25
         * 25
         */

        sc.close();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your porpose is just to print out the result, you can convert your RDD into a java list using the method collect(). this will allow you to apply the java method forEach().

Example:

```
myRDD.collect().forEach( System.out::println );
```